# Iterate each row and perform update accordingly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL SQL that should look for a backslash in a column called `source_username` and if it finds the backslash, it should replace the current value of the `source_username` column with the same value without the characters before the backslash.

For example:

before source_username: domain\username

after source_username:   username

```
with os_user as (
    select source_username from itpserver.managed_incidents mi;
),
osUserWithoutDomain as (
         select (
                        case when (select * from os_user) ilike '%\\%' and (select position('-' in (select * from os_user))>= 1) and (select length((select * from os_user)) != (select position('-' in (select * from os_user))) + 1)
    then (
select substring(

               (select * from os_user),(select position('\' in (select * from os_user)) + 1),(select length((select * from os_user)) - 1)
           ))
      else ((select * from os_user))

end
)
)




UPDATE itpserver.managed_incidents SET source_username  = replace(source_username, (select * from os_user), (select * from osUserWithoutDomain)),
                                       description  = replace(description , (select * from os_user), (select * from osUserWithoutDomain)),
                                       additional_info  = replace(additional_info , (select * from os_user), (select * from osUserWithoutDomain)),
                                       typical_behavior  = replace(typical_behavior , (select * from os_user), (select * from osUserWithoutDomain)),
                                       raw_description  = replace(raw_description , (select * from os_user), (select * from osUserWithoutDomain));
```

This SQL works fine when I have only one row in the table.

If I have multiple rows, I need to specify the row that I want to work with by adding `where id = <id>`

I wish to iterate all the relevant rows (all the rows that `source_username` contains backslash) and on each row to perform the SQL above.

I tried to do this with LOOP:

```
create or replace function fetcher()
returns void as $$
declare 
emp record;
begin 
for emp in select * 
from itpserver.managed_incidents
order by id
limit 10
loop 
    
raise notice '%', emp.id;

<my sql> where id = emp.id

end loop;
end;
$$language plpgsql;


select fetcher();
```

However, I get an error because I don't think it likes the 'with' statement.

Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: That would be a single `UPDATE` statement rather than a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's far simpler than that.  You need to use the `SUBSTR` and `STRPOS` functions.  Take a look at the results of this query.

https://dbfiddle.uk/9-yPKn6E

```
with os_user (source_username) as (
  select 'domain\username'
  union select 'mydomain\joe'
  union select 'janet'
)
select u.source_username
, strpos(u.source_username, '\')
, substr(u.source_username, strpos(u.source_username, '\') + 1)
from os_user u
```

| source_username | strpos | substr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| domain\username | 7 | username |
| janet | 0 | janet |
| mydomain\joe | 9 | joe |

What you need is:

```
UPDATE itpserver.managed_incidents
SET source_username  =                                             substr(source_username, strpos(source_username, '\') + 1)
  , description      = replace(description      , source_username, substr(source_username, strpos(source_username, '\') + 1))
  , additional_info  = replace(additional_info  , source_username, substr(source_username, strpos(source_username, '\') + 1))
  , typical_behavior = replace(typical_behavior , source_username, substr(source_username, strpos(source_username, '\') + 1))
  , raw_description  = replace(raw_description  , source_username, substr(source_username, strpos(source_username, '\') + 1));
```

This is based on lengthy experience with SQL Server and some quick document searches for Postgresql.  The `UPDATE` statement may not work as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

SQL by design/default works on complete data sets. It thus eliminates LOOPS entirely from the language - they are not needed. (Well not quite there are *recursive* queries). Your task is accomplished in a single update statement with a simple regular expression. See documentation [String Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html):

```
update managed_incidents
   set source_username = regexp_replace(source_username,'.*\\(.*)','\1');
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y1zUA2r-).

**Main Take away**: Drop procedural logic terminology (for, loop, if then, ...) from your SQL vocabulary. (you choose alternatives with *case*.)